# How to make new grid data to show based on different filter criteria in JavaScript(angularjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

As you can see I create two JSON.data file, if list equals A-1 i will get json data under there, otherwise I will get the all the main data under data.json.

What I am trying to achieve is, under 'List' I have 3 other check box selection such as 'B-1', 'C-1' and 'D-1' so when one of this check box selected I want to get data in there. I can do this by creating multiple json file. But I was wondering if I put all of this data under one json file, and whenever I select the data it will only show that data on grid.

```
 get: function(selectedFilters, callback) {
      if(selectedFilters['List'] == 'A-1'){
        $http.get('dummy_data/data-list-asc.json?'+serialize(selectedFilters)).then(callback);
      }else{
        $http.get('dummy_data/data.json?'+serialize(selectedFilters)).then(callback);
      }
```

Comment: You could add a field for the filter to your data, and filter on that in the ng-repeat.

Comment: Do you have any example filer in the ng-repeat?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the data inside different properties of a single JSON object. Just add another key, value layer.

For example, if you have for A-1.json:

```
{
  "foo": 1,
  "bar":2
}
```

And for B-1.json:

```
{
  "foo": 3,
  "bar": 4
}
```

These can be consolidated into:

```
{
  "A-1": {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2
  }
  "B-1": {
    "foo": 3,
    "bar": 4
  }
}
```

Of course you have to change the script that reads these files accordingly.

Another option would be to use a normal database, and organize your data by collections. Check out [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) if you haven't.

Comment: my data.json has its just like that, but when I called if statement for just to get A-1 filter its doesnt work, all data shows.

Comment: "if" statements are not how you do that. Access this information from the main object, data.json, like so: data["A-1"]

Comment: Thanks @awimley I always used if, else if, else statements, I will try to see if I can access from main object like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your controller to:

```
function SampleController($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.selectedList = "A-1";
  vm.data =   [
      {list:"A-1", foo:"item 1"}, 
      {list:"A-1", foo:"item 2"},
      {list:"B-1", foo:"item 3"},
      {list:"B-1", foo:"item 4"}
  ];
}
```

and your html to:

```
<label for="listSelect"> select List: </label><br>
<select name="listSelect" ng-model="vm.selectedList">
  <option value="A-1">A-1</option>
  <option value="B-1">B-1</option>
</select><br>      

<div ng-repeat="item in vm.data | filter:vm.selectedList">
   {{item.foo}}
</div>
```

Here is a working example in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RGlg5U

Comment: this is really good but my data set will be like this   {"name": "A-10","Depot":"ABC", "total":"0", "lmp_act":"2",  "lmp_req":"23", }                                              So when A-1 selected I wont to see everything in A-1 printed on grid(horizantol) At the same time I will make that dropdown to checkbox so if A-1 and B-2 selected grid will show those to selected. I will try to put my code on plunkr to explain thing better.